# Split string and append them to an array

Tags: arrays, c, split

Let's say I have a string containing integers "1 3 4 9" and I want to separate them based on the whitespace between them, and then save them into an array.

For example:

Input:

```
char str[] = "1 3 4 9";
int arr[4];
```

Then arr should be like:

```
arr[] = {1, 3, 4, 9}
```

How to do that in C, please help me. Hope I made the question clear

Comment: You need [`strtok`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) and [`strtol`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/)

Comment: What is `array`?

Comment: Just a random variable which is itself a character array

Comment: So that would be `char array[4];`, right? What should that array contain after? `{1,3,4,9}` or `{'1','3','4','9'}`? Could you have e.g. `char str[] = "12 34 56 78"`? Or do you rather want `int array[4];` as your comment below suggests? The question incomplete. Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: Yes edited. And yes, I want the array to contain `{1,3,4,9}`

Comment: Use `strtol` for each of the tokens.

Comment: Can you please give me the code as an answer, I cannot figure it out properly.

Comment: If you cannot figure it out how to use [`strtol`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) even if you have an example in the link I've provided, then ask an other question about this specific topic. Don't forget to show your failing code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`strtok`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "1 3 4 9";
    char *token = strtok(str, " ");
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I used strtok only, but how should I add the individual tokens to an integer array?

Answer (score 0):

Your desired functionality in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "1 3 4 9";
    char newstr[50];
    char *token = strtok(str, " ");
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", token);
        strcat(newstr, token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    printf("Newstr: %s",newstr);

    return 0;
}
```

It will work with any string which will be including white space in it.